# Can you change the flex-direction of flexbox dynamically in CSS and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Given a variable, isRow, if true I want to display the the flex-direction: row but if it is false I want to the flex direction: column.

If there is a way to do this differently than what I am attempting, please let me know!

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("flex-container")[0].style.flex-direction = "row";
//can I use: document.getElementById("flex-cointainer") instead?
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > p {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "flex-container">
  <p id="p1">Hello World!</p>
  <p id="p2">Hello World!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Just create another class called like flex-row that sets flex direction row and conditionally apply the class

Comment: Honestly the easiest way to do it is by using a CSS class and `element.classList.remove("mystyle")` `element.classList.add("mystyle");` to toggle it

Comment: use `document.getElementsByClassName("flex-container")[0].style.flexDirection = "row";`

Comment: One thing that stands out here is `style.flex-direction`. You would need `style.flexDirection`.

Comment: Thank you for everyone for your help, changing it to `style. flexDirection` did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change `style.flex-direction` to `style.flexDirection` and about your comment , yes you can use `document.getElementById("flex-cointainer")` but first you have to add id to your element like

`<div class="flex-container" id="flex-container">`

and here is full working code :

```js
var isRow = true;
var myContainer = document.getElementById("flex-container");
if(isRow) {
  myContainer.style.flexDirection = "row";
}else {
  myContainer.style.flexDirection = "column";
}
```

```css
#flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

#flex-container > p {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<head>
<body>
<div id="flex-container">
<p id="p1">Hello World!</p>
<p id="p2">Hello World!</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```